# Удаление записей из таблицы.

Tags: phpmyadmin, php, mysql

Каким-то образом в таблице b_user_group оказалось 86532259 записей. Причем USER_ID после 1839 идут стотысячные. 
А пользователей на сайте всего 1839.

Просто удалить записи sql запросом (where USER_ID > 1839) не получается, все виснет. Как можно выйти из этого положения?

Comment: удаляйте частями. where user_id>2000 and user_id<50000...

Comment: цикл + sleep

Comment: Зайдите на мой вопрос: http://hashcode.ru/questions/174492/php-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0-%D0%B2-mysql
Я тоже такое спрашивал.

Comment: ваш вопрос отличается

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Может пойти с другого конца - скопировать первые 1839 пользователей в другую таблицу, уничтожить исходную, переименовать новую в старую